# How can get the value from the third table in laravel and order by with id in descending order

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In controller i have a code like this :

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $course=Student::with('StudentDetail')->get();
        $courses=$course->toArray();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($courses);exit;
        return view('student.student_listing',['result'=>$courses]);

    }
```

through this i am getting result like :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Neha
            [email] => neha@sob.com
            [roll_no] => 101
            [created_at] => 2018-05-22 09:20:18
            [updated_at] => 2018-05-22 00:00:00
            [student_detail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [student_id] => 1
                    [phone] => 11691110876
                    [course] => Java
                    [city] => Goa
                    [state] => 1
                    [created_at] => 2018-05-22 16:48:36
                    [updated_at] => 2018-05-22 09:20:43
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Ankit
            [email] => Ankit@sbo.com
            [roll_no] => 102
            [created_at] => 2018-05-22 09:20:18
            [updated_at] => 2018-05-22 00:00:00
            [student_detail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [student_id] => 2
                    [phone] => 12313311
                    [course] => Phps
                    [city] => Delhi
                    [state] => 2
                    [created_at] => 2018-05-23 13:28:19
                    [updated_at] => 2018-05-15 03:15:13
                )

        )

)
```

> Here i am getting a field state where i am getting the id this id
>   related to the states table id how can i get the value from states
>   table bassed on this id and i want this result in Descending order
>   with name or id how can i do that can anyone please help me related
>   this .

models i have like :

```
StudentDetail Model:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Model\Student;
use App\Http\Model\State;
class StudentDetail extends Model
{ 
    public function Student()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);

    }
  public function state()
    {
         return $this->hasOne(State::class);

    }

}



Student model:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Model\StudentDetail;

class Student extends Model
{ 
     public function StudentDetail()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StudentDetail::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested `with()`

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $course=Student::with(['StudentDetail' => function($query){

           $query->with('state);
}])->get();
        $courses=$course->orderBy('studentDetail.state');
        echo "<pre>";print_r($courses);exit;
        return view('student.student_listing',['result'=>$courses]);

    }
```

Or you can simply get using.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $course=Student::with('StudentDetail.state')->get();;
        $courses=$course->orderBy('studentDetail.state');;
        echo "<pre>";print_r($courses);exit;
        return view('student.student_listing',['result'=>$courses]);

    }
```

Comment: but u cannot order by `state id`

Comment: @arun order by parent?

Comment: `result in Descending order with name or id` please include code to achieve that too.

Comment: @arun try `$course->orderBy('studentDetail.state');` see my updated answer

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'states.student_detail_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `states` where `states`.`student_detail_id` in (1, 2)) getting error with second method

Comment: controller :   public function index(Request $request)
    {
        //$course=Student::with('StudentDetail')->get();
        $course=Student::with('StudentDetail.state')->get();
        $courses=$course->toArray();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($courses);exit;
        return view('student.student_listing',['result'=>$courses]);
   
    }

Comment: @Shruti $courses=$course->orderBy('StudentDetail.state.id')->toArray();

Comment: It was a mistake on your code but now its working fine error ..missing single quotes

Comment: Adnan Mumtaz@ i have one more question can u please help me related that ?? should i need to ask ?? dont be irritate

Comment: $course=Student::with(['StudentDetail' => function($query){
        $query->with('state');
         }])->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $courses=$course->toArray();
this is working fine but if also i have country id is studentdetail table then how can i access the country  name along with this code ?? i am asking beacuse i am facing that kind of issues in laravel eloquent